# UITableView isn't updating when didChangeObject is called NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController with my UITableView. I successfully receive delegate calls to `- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath` but none of the changes I make to insert/update/delete rows in the UITableView actually show up. I even just try to set the background color on the UITableView to see if any changes will show up, but they don't show up unless I push a new view controller and then pop back. Then I'll see the background color and the table updates.

My implementation of the didChangeObject: method is really just the boilerplate template:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

I added a button in the navbar with an IBAction which just calls `[self.tableView reloadData];` and whenever I tap that, then all of the insertions and updates show up in the table. However, they don't show up as the changes happen.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you also confirm that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't called?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called during updates, however those updates don't actually show in the UI. During inserts, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is also called, but those rows never show up in the UI.

Comment: Weird, what does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` look like?

Comment: Found the problem, check the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the delegate calls to `didChangeObject` (and the other methods) are not happening on the Main thread which means they can't update the UI, but those changes were just silently being dropped.

I updated the three methods I included above so that the bodies of those methods were all dispatched on the main thread and everything works as expected. Here is an example below:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that in a separate thread, check the raywenderlich implementation:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: There might be a bigger issue here where you should make sure that the changes to your context are happening on the main thread as well.

Comment: Did you ever find out why these delegate calls were happening on a background thread? I have a child context in the background, and when it saves it's causing these calls to happen in the background. I would expect the child context to push changes to the main context on save. The FRC is using the main context, so I can't find the issue.